# HSQLDB 2.2.9 Running scripts + SqlFile

Tags: sql, hsqldb

When I was searching for some HSQLDB samples of how running SQL scripts I found in [HSQLDB 2.2.9 Javadoc documentation](http://hsqldb.org/doc/src//org/hsqldb/cmdline/SqlFile.html) that there is a perfect sample in *src/org/hsqldb/sample/SqlFileEmbedder.java* and it uses some classes {*org.hsqldb.cmdline.SqlFile*} and {*org.hsqldb.cmdline.SqlToolError*} that hsqldb-2.2.9.jar does not contain (!!!) but it's weird because I used Maven for downloading the libraries...

Maven dependency:

```
  <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hsqldb</groupId>
        <artifactId>hsqldb</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.9</version>
  </dependency>
```

Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong?
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a separate jar for SqlTool, which contains SqlFile. This jar is included in the HSQLDB download package available from http://hsqldb.org

The maven directory for org.hsqldb is here and contains the sqltool artifact as well.

https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/releases/org/hsqldb/

Comment: Thank you @fredt, that was my problem. I just added a [new dependency](http://search.maven.org/#artifactdetails%7Corg.hsqldb%7Csqltool%7C2.2.9%7Cjar) to my pom.xml and everything is fine.